# How do I format input phone number without plugin in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to format my `<input id="phone_number" type="tel">` on `keypress`

The requirements of my input field are:

- numbers only and no letters and other special characters
- format the input field with a US number like `(123) 457-7890`

This is my current code:

```
jQuery("#phone_number").on("keypress", function(event) {
    var reg = /[0-9]/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(!reg.test(key)){
        // return false if NOT number
        return false;
    } else {
        // numbers only
        var phone_value = jQuery("#phone_number").val();
        var number = phone_value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/,"$1-$2-$3");
        jQuery("#phone_number").val(number);
    }
});
```

**Problem**: The problem with my code is that it is not able to limit `length` of my input

`Final Output` should look like `(123) 457-7890` first 3 digits enclosed in a parentheses

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please remember to only include relevant tags with your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this should give you what is needed. You were very close to the answer.

I have limited the length of `<input>` using the `maxlength` attribute and added parenthesis in your `phone_value.replace()` function surrounding `$1`.

```js
jQuery("#phone_number").on("keypress", function(event) {
    var reg = /[0-9]/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(!reg.test(key)){
        // return false if NOT number
        return false;
    } else {
        // numbers only
        var phone_value = jQuery("#phone_number").val();
        var number = phone_value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/,"($1) $2-$3");
        jQuery("#phone_number").val(number);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="phone_number" type="tel" maxlength="14">
```

Comment: Thank yo for this. Can you please explain the line `/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/` .. How does that able to limit the `first set` of digits to 3 then `second set` to 3 then `third set` to 4 digits?

Comment: That line will just group the digits into a set of 3 digits, 3 digits and 2 digits. `$1` represents the first set, `$2` represents the second and `$3` the third. Then your replace does the trick. So, if you enter 1234577890, it will replace "123" by "(123)" then "457" by " 457" and "78" by "-78". The "90" is kept as it is. So the output is "(123) 457-7890". Hope you understood it!